Getting conflicting errors from Azure Notification Hub
Trying to set up firebase messaging for ANH. When I input the private key, it gives me this error:
Invalid Fcm V1 credential. InvalidDataContractException: Cannot generate bearer token. Error message: PKCS8 data must be contained within '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' and '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'. (Parameter 'pkcs8PrivateKey')
Ok, so I add the prefix and suffix (literally copy-pasted from the error message), and then get this error:
Invalid Fcm V1 credential. InvalidDataContractException: Cannot generate bearer token. Error message: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
Is there any way around this? I was able to successfully create my dev key but have no idea how. Mandating that a key be base-64 encoded and also mandating that it include a syntax key that includes a non-base-64 character ("-") seems kafkaesque.

Refer to this link for Send push notifications

The error indicates that the provided private key is not in the correct format.
The input is not a valid Base64 string because it contains a non-Base64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character within the padding characters.
The Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API key format generally follows this pattern:
AIza[Base64-encoded string]


Refer  this link to modify the Base58 encoding scheme used primarily in Bitcoin to represent binary data as human-readable strings.

Refer  this link for instructions on how to use a certificate with Azure Notification Hubs.
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQD...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----



Refer to this link for instructions on how to decode an SSL certificate using Python.


Refer to this link to send push notifications using Azure Notification Hubs and Firebase SDK. You can find different ways to do this, such as using GCM credentials for Android, APNS credentials for iOS, etc.
